# How to SignIn using Facebook with Owin?

Tags: c#, authentication, owin, asp.net-identity

Here is what I am trying to do:

First I am creating a `UserManager`

```
var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new CustomUserStore());
```

Since any user is valid, I created a `CustomUserStore` and changed the `FindById` method

```
public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<IdentityUser>
{
    public override Task<IdentityUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        return Task.Run<IdentityUser>(() =>
        {
            return new IdentityUser
            {
                Id = userId,
                UserName = userId
            };
        });
    }
}
```

Then I tried to create a identity

```
var user = new IdentityUser("anyusername");
var identity = userManager.CreateIdentity(
                   user,
                   DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

Then I tried to use the `SignIn` method from `IAuthenticationManager` of `OwinContext`

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        IsPersistent = true
    }, identity);
```

Everything works without throwing any exceptions, but when I try to access a simple action with `Authorize` attribute, it won't let me see the page, as if I was not signed in.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

For more context, I've added the full code here:

- [Startup.Auth.cs](http://pastebin.com/gkHdUfkc)
- [AccountController.cs](http://pastebin.com/iDaHfiGN)

Why is it not signing in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FacebookAuthenticationProvider's `OnAuthenticated` happens at some different context and I cannot Sigin withing this event.

Running on

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
```

Works as expected.