# Capturing login event so I can cache other user information

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've built a web application. When I built it I ticked 'Organizational Accounts'

It works well - I log in with my Office 365 account and `User.Identity.Name` contains the email address

This application is a replacement front end for an older ASP Classic app. The App has an existing security table that I need to use.

I want to use the email address to look up a record in this table to get

- The internal database key for the user (so I can use it in database calls)
- The security level (authorisation) for the user

I want to look this up as soon as I am authenticated and save these two values to `Session` to refer to later

I have an existing method that does all of this lookup and caching. I actually got it working by calling it from the `_LoginPartial.cshtml` view but clearly it is incorrect to be triggering this kind of thing from a view

Here's the code to look up and cache user info. For now this is in `AccountController.cs` but it doesn't have to be

```
private Boolean GetAdditionalUserInfo()
{
    // if authentication info is saved, don't go find it
    if (Session["UID"] != null) return true;

    // get the db employee id from the database and save it to the session
    var r = (
            from e in db.Employees
            where e.Email == User.Identity.Name
            select new
            {
                e.Emp_ID,
                e.Group_ID
            }
            ).SingleOrDefault();

    if ((r == null) || (r.Group_ID == (int)Role.Inactive))
    {
        // couldn't find record or inactive
        return false;
    }

    // Update last login datetime
    Employee ell = db.Employees.Find(r.Emp_ID);
    ell.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;
    db.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Save user details to the session
    Session["UID"] = r.Emp_ID;
    // TBD: Investigate "CLAIMS" - this should probably be a claim
    Session["Role"] = r.Group_ID;

    return true;

}
```

I think the reference to `User.Identity.Name` triggers the login process so I could either just try and call this at startup (I don't know the correct way to do this), or I think the proper thing to do is to call this using the `OnAuthentication` method, and to link it up I should pass the name of my function to the `OnAuthenticated` property. Here's two links to the method and property:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onauthentication(v=vs.118).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.microsoftaccount.microsoftaccountauthenticationprovider.onauthenticated(v=vs.113).aspx

**But I have to say that OO programming is not my thing and I can't work out from these pages how to use them or which class to put them into.**

This [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456008/how-do-i-access-microsoft-owin-security-xyz-onauthenticated-context-addclaims-va) implies it needs to go into `Startup.Auth.cs` but my `Startup.Auth.cs` looks nothing like that one. Here is most of my `Startup.Auth.cs` which was mostly autogenerated when I ticked 'organisational' at the start. (On a side note, `app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();` is my next challenge because apparently organisational login doesn't work with `Session` can you believe it!!!)

Can anyone help me add required code to call `GetAdditionalUserInfo()`? after login? Or alternatively confirm that I can just call this at startup, and suggest the correct way to do it.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
//private static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;
// to make this multi tenant, use common endpoint, not the tenant specific endpoint
private static string authority = aadInstance + "common";

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737578/asp-net-sessionid-owin-cookies-do-not-send-to-browser
    app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(
        new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                // If you don't add this, you get IDX10205
                // from here http://charliedigital.com/2015/03/14/adding-support-for-azure-ad-login-o365-to-mvc-apps/
                ValidateIssuer = false                        
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
                {
                    bool isAjaxRequest = (ctx.Request.Headers != null && ctx.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest");

                    if (isAjaxRequest)
                    {
                        ctx.Response.Headers.Remove("Set-Cookie");
                        ctx.State = NotificationResultState.HandledResponse;
                    }

                    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
   }
}
```

Comment: How does the user get authenticated today? Does `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` work for you?

Comment: Yes. Authentication works fine. I don't know how to utilise OnAthenticated. I've looked these code sample but they don't resemble my code, and autocomplete doesn't show that OnAuthenticated is valid in any part. Here's the code samples I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758485/how-to-pass-information-from-onauthenticated-event-to-a-controller-and-signin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456008/how-do-i-access-microsoft-owin-security-xyz-onauthenticated-context-addclaims-va/19530628#19530628. I'll also edit the question with more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In article [The OWIN OpenID Connect Middleware](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2473126&seqNum=2) you can find detailed explanation how you could use `Notifications`. In you case you should subscribe to `SecurityTokenValidated`:

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx => {...},
SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
{
    string userID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

    // Here you can retrieve information from Database. Let's say you get r.Group_ID.

    var role = r.Group_ID;

    // You can now add it to Identity and no need to use session.

    Claim roleClaim = new Claim(
        "http://nomatterwhatyouput/role",
        role,
        ClaimValueTypes.[RoleType],
        "LocalAuthority");
    context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(roleClaim);

    // Do same for all values you have. Remember to set unique claim URL for each value.

    return Task.CompletedTask;
},
```

And then you can retrieve those values in you actions as mentioned in that article:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var role = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://nomatterwhatyouput/role");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Mate this is _exactly_ what I'm after. I had to change the code a bit and I'll post it. You actually solved my other issue around `Session`. I'm really pleased because I think with this claims thing I can just use method decorators for security. Absolutely fantastic!